# tracking invoice address type migration

Tags: p2sh, p2pkh, p2wpkh, p2tr

I'd love to see charts with stats on percent of utxos by invoice address type (specially P2PKH, P2SH, P2SH-P2WPKH, P2WPKH, P2TR), over time; and same for percent of coin supply.

No doubt I can pay a company to access these numbers. **Is there any alternative free as in free beer?** I could pay my own time working my way through some open source software able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think Pieter's answer provides exactly what you were asking for with the [UTXO set repartition by output type](https://txstats.com/dashboard/db/utxo-set-repartition-by-output-type), I think that you may also be interested in the [Output Types by Count](https://transactionfee.info/charts/output-type-distribution-count/?avg=28&start=2016-01-01&end=2021-09-22) chart on transactionfee.info:

[image]

The site has also more related charts that may be interesting in the context such as

- [Input Types by Count](https://transactionfee.info/charts/inputs-types-by-count/)
- [Output Types by Value](https://transactionfee.info/charts/output-type-distribution-amount/)

and [various charts](https://transactionfee.info) for specific output types.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the first on https://txstats.com/dashboard/db/utxo-set-repartition-by-output-type?orgId=1. For a version weighed by value you can look at the graphs of the individual output types on the same site.